# Trying to configure Debezium image for Elasticsearch Sink

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm trying to use `debezium/connect:1.3` docker image, and facing below error when trying to create elastic-sink using this [tutorial](https://debezium.io/blog/2018/01/17/streaming-to-elasticsearch/).

As [this](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/unwrap-smt/docker-compose.yaml) compose file suggest to use `debezium/connect-jdbc-es`, which seems to be not available.

```
{
    "error_code": 500,
    "message": "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connector, name='io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connector', version='1.3.1.Final', encodedVersion=1.3.1.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-db2/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector', version='1.3.1.Final', encodedVersion=1.3.1.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mongodb/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector', version='1.3.1.Final', encodedVersion=1.3.1.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector', version='1.3.1.Final', encodedVersion=1.3.1.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-oracle/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector', version='1.3.1.Final', encodedVersion=1.3.1.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-postgres/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector', version='1.3.1.Final', encodedVersion=1.3.1.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-sqlserver/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='2.6.0', encodedVersion=2.6.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='2.6.0', encodedVersion=2.6.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.6.0', encodedVersion=2.6.0, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='2.6.0', encodedVersion=2.6.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='2.6.0', encodedVersion=2.6.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='2.6.0', encodedVersion=2.6.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='2.6.0', encodedVersion=2.6.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='2.6.0', encodedVersion=2.6.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [install the Elasticsearch sink connector separately](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/unwrap-smt/debezium-jdbc-es/Dockerfile#L16) or use the Kafka Connect images from Confluent and install Debezium into those

https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql